# Generate Compressed HTML From GridView Control in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

Is there any Possibility that it can Generate Compressed HTML from the GridVIew ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not suggest to do that, but I can give an idea for how I will try to do that:
You can render the GridView in a string, make the compression and then show it to the page.

```
TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter GrapseMesaMou = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    cGridView.RenderControl(GrapseMesaMou);

    // this is the string that you show on page (eg place it on a literal)
    string cFinalResults = CompressHtml(stringWriter.ToString());

    // not show it any more...
    cGridView.Visible = false;
```

one html compressor: http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/

I do not know if this can work smoothly for all cases, but you can give it a try to see if it is what you look for.

Comment: ok...Thanks for your reply.. Can you tell me why should i don't compress the HTML.. ??

Comment: @RickJackson You spend a lot of time to compress it, and the gZip is all ready do good work for compressing the page before send it. The only reason for compress it is if you wish to save it in a cache in a database, and you read it a lot, write it rare.

Comment: Hey Aristos Instead of coding for that manually i can use gzip on the IIS and it will do my job... so can you please help me to find a good article for that...